# Android Development: setWallpaper from resource and web

Tags: android

I can not really figure how to change my home wallpaper from either resource or a URL.
Whould really apprieciate if you tell me or send a link to a new developer :)

//from me to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android 2.0 +**

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) on the developer site:

```
public void setStream (InputStream data)
```

> Change the current system wallpaper to a specific byte stream. The give InputStream is copied into persistent storage and will now be used as the wallpaper. Currently it must be either a JPEG or PNG image.

**Older Android 1.6 and below**

See [Context class](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Context.html#setWallpaper%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
public abstract void setWallpaper (InputStream data)
```

Comment: Thank you but i do not really get the data thing and combining this with public abstract void setWallpaper (InputStream data).

Comment: Sorry i havent figure out how yet :( how to combine the method?

Comment: You have to read your image in as a Stream and pass that into the function.  Or read it as a bitmap and pass that instead of a stream because setWallpaper is overloaded with that function.